# Get Security Descriptor for Windows Driver in Powershell?

Tags: windows, powershell, driver

What I would like to do, is use Powershell to figure out which drivers on Windows can be accessed by arbitrary programs / users. Please excuse me if I am asking this incorrectly, as I am new to the terminology surrounding Windows drivers and don't fully understand the security model involved.

My understanding is that .sys drivers communicate over something like a file descriptor, which can be ACL'ed using "security descriptors." You would open something like "\\.\webssx" for communication with the driver.

While I have found powershell commands to list the drivers, what I would like to find out is which drivers do not restrict the programs which can interact with them. My purpose is to identify the drivers with bad ACLs and fix this manually.

Is this possible in Powershell? Am I approaching this correctly?

Please let me know if this would fit better in Server Fault.

Comment: What problem are you actually trying to fix?

Comment: I am a security researcher, I am trying to enumerate drivers which a low privileged user can send data to. I.E the ACLs don't prevent you from fuzzing the driver without Admin rights.

Comment: Why does it matter? Is there a vulnerability you're trying to fix?

Comment: From my understanding, those security descriptors are set when the sys file is installed by directives in the inf. So the place I'd look for that info is in the inf files in the DriverStore. Ala `gci C:\windows\system32\driverstore\ -recurse -include *.inf`

Comment: @BenH - no, file SD here absolute not related. exist Security Descriptors on DeviceObjects - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff563688(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @BenH That would just give me the names of the entire inf file, I was hoping for a power shell command or some such that got me closer to answering my question without performing adhoc parsing of the inf files. "Windows, which drivers may I converse with?"